# Context Menu Defaults

Tags: javascript, html, contextmenu, right-click

I have some buttons which use animated sprite sheets, and therefore must be set as a background image (as far as I know). Currently they use a javascript redirect rather than a href and so the context menu on right click is for a background image.

Ideally I would like it to show the context menu for a link so that 'open in new tab/window' (or browser equivalent) can be used from a right click.

I do not want to create a custom context menu, just to have it use the browsers standard menu for links, rather than background images.

Unfortunately google hasn't been much help in this matter.

Comment: why not wrap the buttons with actual anchors? BTW you probably meant javascript and not java redirect.

Comment: Yeah I meant javascript. Ideally I would like to use anchors but I would also like a very brief pause before the redirect to allow the button animation to play, literally just half a second. Problem is everything I have found says that this is only possible with javascript setTimeout, as I am currently using.

Comment: well, then, what's the problem?

Comment: Each button uses javascript for the animation and redirect, however since it is not actually a href right clicking on it will display the context menu for a background image. I would like it to display the context menu for a href.

Comment: ok, again - why not use anchors?

Comment: Different browsers seem to handle it differently.

<script type="text/javascript">
function linkTo(url){
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location =url; }, 800);
  }
</script>



<a href="javascript:linkTo('http://www.google.com');">Test Link</a>


That functions great in Chrome but in Firefox and Opera middle clicking the link opens just the javascript function, and in IE and Safari the middle click functions as a left click because window.location tells it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML5 specifications updated hyperlinks to allow them to [contain flow content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html). If you want that kind of behavior, you need to wrap them with a hyperlink like @Eliran suggested.

There's no support for modifying the context menu and the closest thing you have to that is overriding the default right click event handling with something that creates HTML menus.

Comment: Thanks. I have since found a different method to delay a href redirect which solves most of the issues I was having before so no longer need a solution for this. Link included for anyone stumbling upon this by chance years down the line: http://jsfiddle.net/2WJH9/