# JavaScript: Custom Widget with Default Context Menu

Tags: hyperlink, contextmenu, right-click

I have created a custom button/widget for opening links. But it doesn't have the context menu options that a regular hyperlink has.

*css:*

```
span.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff1f;
}

span.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffffffff;
}
```

*html:*

```
<span class="button" onclick="onNavButton('http://example.org/')">Example Button</span>
```

*javascript:*

```
window.onNavButton = function(href="/") {
  document.location.href = href;
};
```

I would like the context menu to have browsers' options for opening link in a new tab, new window, copy link to clipboard, etc. Is there a standard call for displaying hyperlink-related context menus? Or do I have to create a completely custom one for my site? I'm using vanilla JavaScript. But, if need be, I can learn to use an extension.

As a side note, is it possible to show the destination URL in the browser's status bar when hovering over the widget, like how is done with a normal hyperlink?

**Edit:** This may be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10325553/4677917).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10325553/4677917).

The element must be wrapped in an anchor tag with an `href`. Unfortunately, it marks the entire element as "visited" once clicked on. But there is probably a way to disable that.

**Edit:** And the answer to disabling it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8014032/4677917)

```
a:visited {
  color: inherit;
}
```